# Get unique object by key in MongoDB driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq

I want to get distinct object based on some key. Here is how I do it in mongodb:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
   [
     { $match: filter },
     {
        $group:
        {
           _id: distinctField,
           value: { $first: "$$ROOT" } // taking any of group because we don't care
        }
     },
     { $replaceRoot : { newRoot: "$value" }}
   ]
)
```

it works as expected. But then I try to do it in C#:

```
public static IAggregateFluent<T> WhereDistinct<T, TKey>(this IMongoCollection<T> collection, FilterDefinition<T> filter, Expression<Func<T, TKey>> distinctField) => 
    collection.Aggregate()
            .Match(filter)
            .Group(distinctField, items => new { Value = items.FirstOrDefault() }) // taking any of group because we don't care
            .ReplaceRoot(arg => arg.Value);
```

And I get an exception:

> Additional information: FirstOrDefault of type System.Linq.Enumerable
>   is not supported in the expression tree {document}.OrderByDescending(c
>   => c.Version).FirstOrDefault().

Is it possible to do it without creating nasty `BsonDocument` query? I know I just can manually write the whole thing, but I'd like to use some linq-pased approach.

Comment: There's no support for the `$$ROOT` special variable currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @chridam , I've got that there is no `clean way` to do this operation.

However, this extension method may be helpful. It does exactly what I wrote in JS, but provide some nice API for C#

```
public static IAggregateFluent<T> WhereDistinct<T, TKey>(this IMongoCollection<T> collection,
    FilterDefinition<T> filter, Expression<Func<T, TKey>> distinctField) =>
    collection.Aggregate()
        .Match(filter)
        .Group(new BsonDocument
        {
            {"_id", $"${((MemberExpression) distinctField.Body).Member.Name}"},
            {"doc", new BsonDocument {{"$first", "$$ROOT"}}} // taking any of group because we don't care
        })
        .ReplaceRoot<T>("$doc");
```